# How can I fix my Ajax Insert Query acting as GET?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, insert-query

I'm very new to Ajax and I've noticed when the "like" button is clicked, the url changes to act as a get. Such as `?videoID=18&userID=11&insert-like=`.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
      var videoID271 = $('#videoID').val();
      var userID271 = $('#userID').val();
      console.log('starting ajax');
      $.ajax({
        url: "./insert-like.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { videoID: videoID271, userID: userID271 },
        success: function (data) {
          var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(dataParsed);
        }
      });

    });
  });

</script>

<form>
<input type="hidden" name="videoID" id="videoID" value="<?php echo $id123; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="userID" id="userID" value="<?php echo $userID; ?>" />
<button type="submit" name="insert-like" style="background:none;border:none;text-decoration:none; color:#DD4400;font-weight:bold">Like</button>
</form>

if($_POST['videoID']) {
    $videoID = $_POST['videoID'];
    $userID = $_POST['userID'];

    $query271 = "INSERT INTO video_likes(video_id,user_id) VALUES(:video_id271,:user_id271)";
    $stmt271 = $pdo->prepare($query271);
    $stmt271->bindValue(':video_id271',$videoID);
    $stmt271->bindValue(':user_id271',$userID);
    $stmt271->execute();
}
```

I tried using this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794652/insert-into-database-mysql-using-ajax-and-php) and changing to my needs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh, and the page refreshes when clicking the like button. That's like the total opposite purpose of Ajax.

Comment: That's consistent with @iJamesPHP2's answer

Comment: `return false` in submit handler.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your button is `type="submit"`

This will make it submit the form normally. Remove it.

Comment: I did that. Still doing the same thing. It's probably an error within Ajax, since I am just learning Ajax - probably something wrong with that.

Comment: @DonaldFaulknor Your AJAX is fine. What I suggested is the problem. Make sure you have actually reloaded your page with your updated code

Comment: Still not working. Is there a reason I don't need an XMLHttpRequest? Like I said, I'm new to Ajax.

Comment: @DonaldFaulknor You don't even need the <form>, try removing that also

Comment: That didn't work, but I found something that did. I added an id to my button and changed `$('button')` to `$('#insertLike')`. It's working now, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @DonaldFaulknor Cool